# Как записать данные в файл на php фоном?

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

Добрый день, такой вопрос:
имеется форма:

```
<form name="create_page" action="create_page" id="create_page1">
<input name="pcreate" type="text" value="Введите имя страницы " id="enter_nameP"></br>
<label for="enter_nameP" >с расширением (.php)</label><br>
<input type="submit" value="Создать">
</form>
```

имеется файл к которому обращается форма, внутри него скрипт создания и записи файла с именем того, что ввели в текстовый инпут.
сответсвенно перебрасывает на другую страницу при клике на сабмит, а как сделать, что-бы фоном это все происходило ?

т.е. нажал, вышло уведомление, что создано и все.

буду благодарен за помощь, просто я с JQ не очень хорошо знаком, если вообще это можно на нем реализовать.

Answer (score 0):

Ну со стороны JS будет выглядеть как-то так :

```
   //Сюда мы попадем когда кликнем на кнопку отправки формы 
   $("#create_page1").submit(function (event) {

        // Говорим браузеру что не нужно отправлять форму и мы сами разберемся что дальше делать
        event.preventDefault(); 

        //получаем какие-то данные с формы
        var name  = $("#enter_nameP").val();

        //создаем запрос Ajax
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "create_page.php",
            data: name
        }).done(function (data) {

            //Сюда мы попадем если все ок
            //Выводим уведомление пользователю какое-то и тд
        }).fail(function (data) {

            //Сюда мы попадем если запрос Ajax обработать не удалось
        });
    });
```

подробнее про jquery Ajax читаем [тут](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)